# How to detect whether a text file is converted through OCR

Tags: c#, ocr

I want to make an application using C#, to check a file whether it is converted through OCR or typed through keyboard

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't be able to tell, should you?  Can you tell what the differences are manually?

Comment: @Merlyn, I have heard about OCR leaves some hidden chars which can't be seen manually.

Comment: @Merlyn: In a perfect text you wouldn't be able to tell, but plenty of times there are indicators of keyboard entry (typos) or OCR (letters replaced with similar-looking character sequences).

Comment: @Javed: Google shows me this - http://forums.adobe.com/message/2633365#2633365 (edit: now links directly to post), but you didn't mention your textual format.  Are you talking about PDFs, plain text, or what document format?

Comment: @Javed: In a .txt file, nothing is hidden - only non-printing characters might be considered "hidden" in some cases (like a less programmer-friendly text editor).  If your text editor can't see these, you can see these in a hex editor.  Can you paste an example of the type of stuff that would make you suspect your doc was input via OCR?

Comment: any other details you can give? What kind of documents are being OCR'd? What language(s) are they going to be in? What is this output going to be used for?

Comment: @Javed, greg:  +1 for Greg.  The culture the docs are in is pretty important.  Many languages have non-unicode characters, and English borrows many (most) of its words from other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This job can be tough to solve in general, and easy to solve for specific cases.

For example, if your OCR software inserts a bunch of non-ASCII characters, and all your documents contain only the letter A through Z, the lower-case letters a-z, digits, and punctuation, then your job is fairly simple.

To solve that problem, you could use a for-loops on characters in the document, and use if statements like `if(char.IsLetter(currentChar))` and `if(char.IsDigit(currentChar))`, or use `char.GetUnicodeCategory` in a switch-statement.

If there are specific words/letters it always gets wrong, you could make a `Dictionary<string, bool>` object, and populate it with words you know the OCR always gets wrong, and/or words that you know a human won't get wrong.  Then, loop over all the words in your document and see if you get a match in your dictionary, proving that it is a human, or OCR.

If you're using OCR software that doesn't tend to screw things up in an easily detectable way, you'd have to resort to artificial intelligence to solve it.  Hopefully you don't have to resort to this, because this is really hard stuff to program, and takes a lot of work to set up correctly and maintain.  From your description and your comments, it sounds like you can use the easier solution.

No matter what, software to do this kind of job is going to get some of the documents wrong.  The user may have typed in something strange, or copy/pasted in some non-ASCII character (such as the word résumé), or the OCR somehow didn't make any detectable mistakes.  Hopefully you have a way to deal with this fact, or your situation isn't risky enough that this is a problem.

Answer (score 4):

When I'm reading something, I can usually tell if it's OCRed by seeing spelling errors that are the result of substituting simular characters for correct ones. For example, `O` and `o`, `S` and `s`, `1` and `l` or `I`, `rn` and `m`, and so on. If you write your program to look for those unusual anomalies, you can probably detect OCRed text.

Similarly, you can look for other spelling errors that typically indicate typed text. For example, transposed letters (`teh`) or letters substituted for one next to them on the keyboard are likely indicators that a text was typed in.

Comment: I have heard about OCR leaves some hidden chars

Comment: I don't know anything about hidden characters. That would depend on the format of the file that the OCR file makes and its algorithms. Maybe some OCR programs store metadata in their generated files about what letters they detected, but I can't help you with that.

Comment: Some of the `unicode` char which can't entered through keyboard are placed by ocr. **ex:** `A` to `Â` or `À`.

Comment: If a "plz give me teh codez" sentence is typed, printed, scanned and OCR'ed, you'll find the "teh" in the OCR output ... regrettably :D

Comment: @belisarius: And if they typed "plz give me teh codez!!11!" then there will be indicators of OCR, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

OCRed text almost always consists of one-line paragraphs. And OCR engines usually have trouble distinguishing some upper/lower case letters and letters with similar looking glyphs, such as S/s, V/v, X/x, O/o/0, 1/l/I, etc.